# Is this sentence correct to give approximate time for meeting?

Tags: grammar

Actually I have to give an approximate time for the meeting.

"We can make it from 8.30 am – 9.30 am"

Is this sentence correct?

Comment: Would you please explain more about the context? Are you organizing a meeting or response when you would be available?

Comment: Your sentence says that you (plural) can be available for one hour: from 8.30 to 9.30.